# Lista Simple circular sin atributo "fin" en Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Qué tal, debo crear una lista simple circular pero debo hacerla sin un atributo que indique el "fin" de la lista, solo con el de inicio o cabecera. el problema es que cuando intento agregarle un primer elemento me lanza un null Pointer Exception. No sé qué hice mal. Aquí les dejo mi código

Los nodos de la lista Almacenan productos

```
 public class NodoProducto {
private NodoProducto siguiente;
private Producto producto;

public NodoProducto(Producto producto){
    this.producto=producto;
}

public NodoProducto getSiguiente() {
    return siguiente;
}

public void setSiguiente(NodoProducto siguiente) {
    this.siguiente = siguiente;
}

public Producto getProducto() {
    return producto;
}

public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
    this.producto = producto;
}
```

}

Esta es la lista

```
public class ListaProducto {

//LISTA SIMPLE CIRCULAR
NodoProducto inicio;
int size;


public ListaProducto(){
    this.size=0;
}

public boolean estaVacia(){
    return inicio==null;

}


public boolean agregarProducto(Producto producto) {
    NodoProducto nuevoProducto= new NodoProducto(producto);

    if(estaVacia()){
        inicio=nuevoProducto;
        nuevoProducto.setSiguiente(inicio);
        size++;
        return true;
    }else{
        NodoProducto aux=inicio;

        boolean flag=false;
        if(inicio.getProducto().getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(producto.getNombre())){
            System.out.println("PRODUCTO REPETIDO");
            return false;
        }

        while(aux.getSiguiente()!=inicio){
            if(aux.getProducto().getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(producto.getNombre())){
                flag=true;
                return false;
            }
            aux=aux.getSiguiente();
        }


        if (flag==false){//Si esto continua false quiere decir que ningun producto se repitió en la lista jeje
            NodoProducto aux2=inicio;
            while(aux2.getSiguiente()!=inicio){
                aux2=aux2.getSiguiente();
            }
            aux2.setSiguiente(nuevoProducto);
            nuevoProducto.setSiguiente(inicio);
            size++;
        }
        return true;

    }

} 





public void printLista(){
    if(estaVacia()){
        System.out.println("LA LISTA ESTA VACIA");
        return;
    }
        NodoProducto aux=inicio;
        String info="";
        while(aux.getSiguiente()!=inicio){
            info+=aux.getProducto().getNombre()+"\n";
            aux=aux.getSiguiente();
        }
        System.out.println(info);
        System.out.println("Hola");
        return;

}
```

}

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar los errores que he cometido

Comment: agrega tu mensaje de error

Comment: No inicias bien la variable NodoProducto inicio. Por eso cuando intentas asignarle un valor te da ese error.